# CSV format to object array with running total

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, lodash, lazy.js

EDIT: How do I go from this :

```
    tickets = [ 
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "08:19 AM", name: "Bernie Sanders" },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:29 AM", name: "Donald Trump" },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:31 AM", name: "Donald Trump" },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:34 AM", name: "Donald Trump" },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:34 AM", name: "Bernie Sanders" },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:07 AM", name: "Mike Huckabee"}
];

    ...
```

to this:

```
tickets = [ 
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "08:19 AM", name: "Bernie Sanders", total: 1 },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:29 AM", name: "Donald Trump", total: 1 },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:31 AM", name: "Donald Trump", total: 2 },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:34 AM", name: "Donald Trump", total: 3 },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:34 AM", name: "Bernie Sanders", total: 2 },
{ date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:07 AM", name: "Mike Huckabee", total: 1}
]
```

I looked through the popular libraries that deal with objects and arrays. For example, underscore.js, lodash.js, lazy.js. I was not able to find anything that will do this

Comment: that's not csv format

Comment: I copied it from a csv file

Comment: show the RAW csv data - because that is *not likely* to be csv ... only 1 comma, and it's in the middle of the Date

Comment: that's not a csv file either ... do you know what the **C** in csv stands for?

Comment: @Burn Son, its look like tab separated spread sheet

Comment: **CSV** would be like `"text here","text here" ... text will (generally) be quoted and each column (field) is separated by a **Comma**.  What you are showing _might_ be **Tab** separated values (TSV) but it _certainly_ is _not_ CSV.

Comment: I opened the csv file, high litre it and selected copy. Then I pasted it in here

Comment: CSV format can have different separators, even though technically it may be TSV, it may still be called CSV... but yes, the separator is what you need to figure out to be able to split the file properly.

Comment: THats not the important part. The important part is how I can get the running total key value pair. Each time that person submits a ticket, the total increases by one. Counting unique instances of when someone sun nuts a ticket. I just need the logic I don't need the raw code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you don't need to support legacy browsers, [vanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) has everything you need:

```js
tickets = [ 
  { date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "08:19 AM", name: "Bernie Sanders" },
  { date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:29 AM", name: "Donald Trump" },
  { date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:31 AM", name: "Donald Trump" },
  { date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:34 AM", name: "Donald Trump" },
  { date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:34 AM", name: "Bernie Sanders" },
  { date: "Jan 05,2016", time: "09:07 AM", name: "Mike Huckabee"}
];

var x = document.getElementById('x');

var runningTotals = {};

var addTotalToTicket = function(ticket){
  if ( ! (ticket.name in runningTotals ) ) {
    runningTotals[ticket.name] = 0;  
  }
  runningTotals[ticket.name]++;
  ticket.votes = runningTotals[ticket.name];
  return ticket;
};

var ticketsWithTotals = tickets.map(addTotalToTicket);

x.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ticketsWithTotals,null,"  ");
```

```css
pre {
  background-color: #ded;
}
```

```html
<pre><code id="x"></code></pre>
```

Comment: what are u sure I need to have vanillajs to do this?

Comment: Correct for the newly asked question... but the OP changed the question.

Comment: but I was able to run this without including vanillaJS

Answer (score 1):

Not mine but that's what you're looking for:

```
// Source: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm
// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray(strData, strDelimiter) {
    // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
    // then default to comma.
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");
    // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
    var objPattern = new RegExp((
    // Delimiters.
    "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +
    // Quoted fields.
    "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +
    // Standard fields.
    "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"), "gi");
    // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
    // a default empty first row.
    var arrData = [[]];
    // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
    // matching groups.
    var arrMatches = null;
    // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
    // until we can no longer find a match.
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec(strData)) {
        // Get the delimiter that was found.
        var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[1];
        // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
        // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
        // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
        // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
        if (strMatchedDelimiter.length && (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)) {
            // Since we have reached a new row of data,
            // add an empty row to our data array.
            arrData.push([]);
        }
        // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
        // let's check to see which kind of value we
        // captured (quoted or unquoted).
        if (arrMatches[2]) {
            // We found a quoted value. When we capture
            // this value, unescape any double quotes.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[2].replace(
            new RegExp("\"\"", "g"), "\"");
        } else {
            // We found a non-quoted value.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[3];
        }
        // Now that we have our value string, let's add
        // it to the data array.
        arrData[arrData.length - 1].push(strMatchedValue);
    }
    // Return the parsed data.
    return (arrData);
}

function CSV2JSON(csv) {
    var array = CSVToArray(csv);
    var objArray = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        objArray[i - 1] = {};
        for (var k = 0; k < array[0].length && k < array[i].length; k++) {
            var key = array[0][k];
            objArray[i - 1][key] = array[i][k]
        }
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify(objArray);
    var str = json.replace(/},/g, "},\r\n");

    return str;
}
```

JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/AZFvQ/

Comment: that's because your data is probably not in *comma separated values* format

Comment: you need to override the comma with your separator character, whichever it is (space or tab?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to get total count of entries for some person, you can use underscore.js [`groupBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) and [`reduce()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) functions

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand

Comment: underscore.js groupBy method is similar to SQL GROUP BY. Check examples http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

Comment: I don't need group the object (not yet). I just need to count each time a specific name appears